# Cannot align Nav Items to right in Bootstrap React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-redux

How can I align my NavItem to right. I can only see it aligned to the left side. Any syntax errors ?

```
 <Navbar style={{backgroundColor:'#071425'}} collapseOnSelect expand="lg"  variant="dark">
     <Nav className="justify-content-end" activeKey="/home">
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link href="/home">hello</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
            Disabled
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    
          </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `<Nav>` element wrapping another `<Nav>` elements. I think that `<Nav>` and `<Nav.Item>` is the same thing so why are you wrapping `<Nav.items>` into another `<Nav>` ?

Try this without this wrapper:

```
    <Navbar
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#071425" }}
      collapseOnSelect
      expand="lg"
      variant="dark"
     >
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/home">hello</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
          Disabled
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
    </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
 <Nav className="ms-auto" activeKey="/home">
      //Your nav items
</Nav>
```

It works on bootstrap 5 [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)